# Upgrade from 7.5 to 8.1 Update 3

Tags: upgrade

We are currently running version Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003) and would like to upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 Update 3.

Does it make sense to do an incremental upgrade in the following order?

1. Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003)
2. Sitecore 8.0
3. Sitecore 8.1
4. Sitecore 8.1 Update 1
5. Sitecore 8.1 Update 2
6. Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to upgrade to 8.2?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Because then you'd have an option of using the [**Express Migration Tool**](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx).

Comment: The feedback I am being given is that "Sitecore versions upgrades are notoriously buggy".

Comment: The Express Migration Tool currently only works when starting from a 7.2 instance.

Comment: Are you using any Sitecore modules?  Upgrading modules can greatly affect your overall upgrade path.

Comment: ActiveCommerce, DAM, Clay Tablet, WFFM, Sitemap XML and Language fallback

Comment: I would look at the upgrade path for each of those modules on dev.sitecore.net.  I know for a fact that the WFFM upgrade *requires* you to go through each step upgrade of Sitecore. With WFFM you can't skip from 8.0 to 8.1 - you have to do all of the individual Sitecore upgrades along the way.  Same going from 8.1 to 8.1 Update-3. It's a complete nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reviewing Sitecore's upgrade documentation (All 8+ versions are listed here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx. Each page has a link to it's Upgrade Guide which indicates pre-requisites for installation) the upgrades you would need to perform to get to Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 would be:

1. Upgrade to Sitecore 8.0 Initial Release (rev. 141212)
2. Upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release (rev. 151003)
3. Upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 (rev. 160519)

At the time of writing this, Sitecore 8.2 Initial Release (rev. 160729) is the most recent version.  If you were to choose to go to this version,  you could skip Step 3 above and perform the upgrade for Sitecore 8.2 Initial Release, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your upgrade path makes sense, but you may be able to skip 8.1.1 and 8.1.2 and go straight to 8.1.3

I was just chatting with a colleague about this a couple of days ago, and it may be worth it to consider using the [8.2 express upgrade tool](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx) and downgrading a version. The only extra consideration is DB changes between 8.1.3 and 8.2 and if there are any then you can upgrade your DBs with a clean sitecore code base following the upgrade path (which should be faster), and upgrade your code base using the express upgrade and then downgrade a version. All in all, you should be able to save yourself a good chunk of effort.